# "Missing number, treated as zero." in LaTex

Tags: latex, roman-numerals

I want to get the Roman number of 2. So I use `$\Roman{2}$` inside text. But then I got an error

> Missing number, treated as zero.

How can I fix it?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This would be better moved to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ - it is in no way a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `\Roman` not `\Rome`. Anyway, `\Roman` prints the value of a counter as a roman numeral, so you can't use it with "2".

Short answer - use `\romannumeral 2`.

Long answer - define commands as described [here](http://yangfeng.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/roman-numerals-in-latex/).

Comment: Thanks! Why sometimes I saw some commands taking arg inside {}, sometimes not?

Comment: LaTeX commands always take arguments inside `{}` or `[]`. The reason is because `\romannumeral` isn't really a LaTeX command, it's a TeX command. Usually you don't want to mess around with those.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use [that snippet](http://nw360.blogspot.com/2007/09/roman-numerals-in-latex.html):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
```

now you can call:

```
\Rmnum{2} % II
\rmnum{2} % ii
```

Comment: Apparently it does not work with something like `\cite[Section \Rmnum{1}]{mycitation}`. Any suggestion on how to fix this?